# JQueryUI Dialog: 'auto' width does not consider vertical scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a JQueryUI Dialog with the `width` property as `'auto'`. Everything works fine except in cases where the content extends beyond the dialog's height: A vertical scrollbar appears (as is intended), but such scrollbar messes up the layout of the dialog's content.

I thought the `width:auto` property would take the scrollbar into account, but it doesn't.

Is there a way to dynamically adapt the width of the dialog in cases where a vertical scrollbar shows up?

Here's the dialog working as I expect it to:
[image]

When I click in the 'Hoja 2' tab, the content changes and the width adjusts automatically:
[image]

As you can see, the scrollbar appears and pushes the second box down.

Comment: _such scrollbar messes up the layout of the dialog's content_, are you able to share image(s) pointing the problem area ?

Comment: added a couple of screenshots!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it wrapping the contents in a div container with `display:flex` as style.